# How to print the content for the ThreadOBJ(CLR thread) from !threads?

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

I want to get the content for the ThreadOBJ  by !do 000000da316cd5b0, which is from the !threads , however it failed, it seems it is not a managed thread , it looks like it is a CLR native thread.
So how to print the content for ThreadOBJ with address 000000da316cd5b0?

```
0:000> !threads
ThreadCount:      179
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 179
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       0
Hosted Runtime:   no

Lock  
   ID OSID ThreadOBJ           State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count Apt Exception
   6    1 1538 000000d5e6ca0340    28220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000d5e6c98550 0     Ukn 
  13    2 37b8 000000da31687880    2b220 Preemptive  000000D8E77C5798:000000D8E77C74F8 000000d5e6c98550 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
  15    3 108c 000000da316cd5b0  102a220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000000d5e6c98550 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker)
```

Also when I type "dt  clr!thread 000000da316cd5b0", it said Symbol clr!thread not found.

```
0:048> dt  clr!thread 000000da316cd5b0
Symbol clr!thread not found.
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue. I also think it worked some time ago with `mscorwks!Thread` and I'm not sure why it does not work any more. I propose to close this question and prefer the more general question you have asked as well. If you get an answer there, it's likely that it also applies to this question.

Comment: While technically, IMHO the question is ok, I still wonder why you want to do this. For all the problems I needed to solve so far, digging into the ThreadObj was not necessary. What information are you missing in the output of `!threads` that is available in ThreadObj?

Comment: I'm ok to close this question.Besides to check  ThreadObj  ,I also need to check other object, such as the the variable  "oldCounts ","counts", "newCounts"  mentioned in the https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp,  as currently I am investigating a thread pool issue.